# A List of wireless network doesn' t show

Tags: wireless

I have tried to follow an official help on how to connect to wireless.

[image]

According to step 2:

[image]

What I need to do is to click network menu and then what is supposed to be is that a list of network show up.

Instead, what is shown is like this:

[image]

There's no list of network at all.

Additional information:

1. The notebook I use is MacBook Pro 2011. There is no wireless hardware switch.
2. Near my computer, there are working wifi routers. I've just switched from mac OS X to Ubuntu  recently. But while I use OS X,  a list consisting many  networks  -including  the one in my house - always show up.

The result of running command

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3 and also: rfkill list all
```

[image]

Comment: It appears that you have no wireless interface at all. It requires not just the hardware, but, crucially, the correct driver. Let's see what you have and try to install a driver. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `rfkill list all` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Please avoid pasting a screenshot of the output of the command, paste the text output instead. Also, would be useful if you add the output of `inxi -SCN -! 31 -y 80`.